How to make NavigationDrawer with all screens using MVI Decompose?
I have a problem with creating NavigationDrawer that has all app screens (except nested screens that other screens open). For example: Home, Details, Contacts, TodoList, About, etc. How I can achieve navigation to any screen I want without circular dependency failure?

For such a simple drawer you probably don't need to extract a separate component. Just show the drawer with all the items in it, then add a method in the component for every drawer item, then call a method on item click, and finally push a configuration using StackNavigation.
